# Exocortex.dsp FFT vs mathematically strict DFT. C# in Unity3d

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft, convolution, dft

I'm calculating the autocorrelation of audio samples. The direct calculation of autocorrelation can be sped from O(n^2) to O(nlogn) by using the the FFT - exploiting the convolution theorem. Both forward and inverse FFT are needed.

I made a test script in python, just to make sure I knew what I was doing, and it works. But in my C# version, it doesn't.

I know that many implementations of the FFT give answers that differ from the mathematically strict DFT. For instance, you may need to divide your results by N (the number of bins.)

... tried that, still didn't work ...

I've striven mightily to find some documentation about the details of Exocortex's FFT, to no avail. (cue someone finding it in < 1 sec...)

Does anyone out there know the details of the Exocortex implementation of FFT, and how to get the mathematically strict values for the DFT, and inverse DFT of a signal?

Answer (score 0):

I've got my code working!

As everybody has probably guessed, there was an additional bug in my code, which was confounding my efforts to understand Exocortex's fft.

In Exocortex's forward fft, you need to divide by the fft size to get the canonical values for the transform. For the inverse fft, you need to multiply by the fft size. I believe this is the same as Apple's Accelerate, whereas in numpy and matlab you get the actual DFT values.

Perhaps the practice of requiring division or multiplication by the fft size is extremely widespread – if you know the situation, I invite you to comment.

Of course, many times people are only interested in fft values relative to each other, in which case scaling by a constant doesn't matter.

If anyone out there knows where there is decent documentation for Exocortex DSP, I invite you to comment on that as well.